# What is the syntax for passing headers using axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Been looking all over but cannot find an answer for this. I am trying to pull the API for my Square POS account but keep getting these errors in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

VM50:1 GET https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list net::ERR_FAILED

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

I have tried pulling the API through Postman and it works fine through there, which leads me to believe something in my syntax is incorrect but I cannot figure out what.

Here is what I have:

```
    export default axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list',
            headers: {
                'Square-Version': '2021-06-16',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        })
```

I am using REACT and NodeJS

Comment: That _is_ the syntax for adding headers, but you can't add _response_ headers on the _client_ - CORS protection would be totally pointless if you could. You shouldn't be connecting to Square from the client, that exposes the token to all of your clients.